# How to call Swift init method from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode10.2

I was using Xcode 10.1 and used SWIFT_VERSION 3.0 in Objective-C project.
The below code worked fine with Swift 3.

RichTextEditor.swift:

```
init(frame: CGRect, editAccess: Int) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
}
```

Objective-C class calls above method:

```
self.rchTextControl = [[RichTextEditor alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, cellRowHeight, tableView.tableView.bounds.size.width-4, cellMessageHeight-cellRowHeight) editAccess:[sectionCtrlEditAccessValue intValue]];
```

Above Objective-C code was working with Swift 3 and once I changed it to SWIFT_VERSION 4, the below error occurred.

[image]

How can I fix this issue? I was googling this but I could not find a solution.

Comment: You have to mark the method explicitly with `@objc`. Try that and see if that works.

Comment: https://justinmiller.io/posts/2015/01/28/swift-objc-initializers/

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `@objc` in method declaration to get access of it in objective c.
like this,

```
class RichTextEditor : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    @objc init(frame: CGRect, editAccess: Int) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```